# Convert markdown to html without css, Any package of SublimeText 2?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, converters, markdown, emmet

Tools and packages out there have been flourished to achieve Markdown2html with various styles of CSS. Oh, come on, who would need the CSS. My simple question is:

**Is there any package that support md2html without css for ST2 ? **

I used to be a VIMer, and the `markdown` plugin could convert. And the [dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus) is nested at webpage, I hate copy all my `md` and then copy back.

Is there any ZenCoding style? Somehow like select all my markdown lines and `command+B` to simply and elegantly changes to html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like [Markdown Preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview)? You could create a key binding for the following command and arguments.

```
{
    "keys": ["<your key binding>"],
    "command": "markdown_preview",
    "args": {
        "target": "sublime",
        "parser": "markdown"
    }
}
```

You would have to add a context to get it to run with cmd+b, but it's doable. Try out the plugin though and see if it does what you want first.

Comment: Oh, thanks~ I dig into the package preference which indicates that I could set the CSS style. In other words, I can just skip CSS. Cool. Thanks for your reminding me of that~~~